# Set LinearLayout in reference to screen size?

Tags: android, xml

I have the following layout in the url.

there are two linearlayouts inside a linear layout (above , below)(vertical) . in the LinearLaoyut above there are two LinearLayouts (horizontal)with a Image (left) and in the other one TWO TextViews (right)...

I want them to set their height and weidth in reference to the screen size.

How can I do it concerning this example?

[image]

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html#Weight

Comment: i tried it with weights but i will not work.. the other problem is the text is so small on big devices... i only want the font also gets bigger in relation to the  size of display